# Долгое закрашивание ячеек datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

В datagridview содержится 770 строк. Необходимо закрасить ячейки в соответствии с тем, какое значение в них содержится. Использую такой код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvControl.RowCount; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            double y = double.Parse(dgvControl[index, i].Value.ToString());
            if (y > _maxY || y < 0)
                style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else if (y >= left && y <= right || y < _minY)
                style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            else
                style.BackColor = Color.White;
            dgvControl[index, i].Style = style;
        }
```

но таким образом закраска происходит очень долго (больше минуты). Что тут неоптимально и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Хрустальный шар показывает, что этот код обёрнут в `try-catch`, валится на `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` из-за `RowCount` (думаю, надо добавить ` - 1`), всё это обернуто в другой цикл... Не? Так-то этот код должен отрабатывать моментально.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хрустальный шар промахнулся, данный кусок кода лежит прямиком в обработчике нажатия кнопки

Comment: Ну, я могу лишь повторить, что данный код должен отрабатывать моментально. Возможно, на датагрид навешаны ещё какие-то события, которые срабатывают при выполнении этого кода?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проверял - события не срабатывают